# Limit points and completeness

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose $y$ is a limit point of the metric space $X$. Show $Y=X\backslash\left\{ y\right\} $ is not complete.

The following is my attempt at a proof. Say $Y$ is complete. Then $Y$ must be closed. Since a subset is closed if and only if it contains all of its limit point, $Y$ must contain all of its limit points. However, $y$ does not belong to $Y$.

I'm not sure if I can call $y$ a limit point of $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

The target is to construct a Cauchy sequence of elements of $Y$ which is *not convergent in $Y$*.

Let $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ be the metric.  If $y$ is a limit point of $X$, then for every $\varepsilon>0$,

$$
B(y,\varepsilon)\cap \big(X\smallsetminus\{y\}\big)=B(y,\varepsilon)\cap Y \ne \varnothing,
$$

where $B(y,\varepsilon)=\{x\in X : d(x,y)<\varepsilon\}$. (This is the definition of the limit point.)

For every $n\in\mathbb N$, pick $y_n\in B(y,1/n)\cap Y$. Clearly $y_n\to y$, as $d(y_n,y)<1/n$, and thus $\{y_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence as it is a convergent one. But $\{y_n\}$ does not converge in $Y$, for if $y_n\to y'\in Y$, then $y'\ne y\not\in Y$, and consequently $\{y_n\}$ would converge to two different points of $X$. Thus we have constructed a Cauchy sequence of elements of $Y$ which does not converge in $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Your argumentation is incorrect. If you ask whether $Y$ is complete, you view $Y$ as a metric space on its own. Hence, it is indeed closed.

You have to find a Cauchy sequence in $Y$ without a limit point.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $y$ is a limitpoint of $X$ allows you to construct a sequence in $Y=X\backslash\left\{ y\right\} $ converging to $y$. This is automatically
a Cauchy sequence. The sequence is contained in $Y$ but has no limit
in $Y$.